# jQuery add ID to parent table then remove TD

Tags: jquery, html-table, addition

I have a TD with an image nested inside it, I want to add an ID to it's parent and then have that TD removed. The following code will remove the TD based on the image that is nested inside it, but before it's removed, I want to add an ID to it's parent table. Any suggestions?

```
$('td img[src="/v/vspfiles/templates/cyberfront/images/RBox_Border_Left_Top.gif"]').parent().remove();
```

Comment: Add id, then delete... what's the problem?

Comment: Want to add the ID to the parent table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('td img[src="/v/vspfiles/templates/cyberfront/images/RBox_Border_Left_Top.gif"]').parent().closest("table").attr('id','newId');

$('td img[src="/v/vspfiles/templates/cyberfront/images/RBox_Border_Left_Top.gif"]').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `closest` and `end`. `closest` finds the nearest ancestor element matching a selector, and `end` returns to the previous selection.

So...

```
$('td img[src="/v/vspfiles/templates/cyberfront/images/RBox_Border_Left_Top.gif"]')
    .parent() // go to the td
        .closest('table') // go to the table
            .prop('id', 'foobar') // set the table's id property
        .end() // go back to the td
        .remove(); // remove it
```

Comment: I think `.end()` is my new favourite function that I didn't know about until today. Cheers for sharing your answer.

Comment: I don't know why this didn't work... It even corrupted the other JavaScript on the page.

Comment: What version of jQuery do you have? If it's an old one (pre 1.6) upgrade it or change `prop` to `attr`. That's the most likely cause for it not working.